# Precision and recall

Tags: precision, evaluation

Lets say I have this data:

```
         Right Wrong
oneName  420   60
twoName  200   40
```

Precison = TP / (TP+FP)

Recall = TP / (TP +FN)

Given this data I understand that precision is:

```
      420(TP)
 420(TP) + 60(FP).
```

However I have a hard time understanding and calculcating FN when you're suppose to calculate recall. What is FN in this scenario?

Comment: Not sure I understand what oneName and twoName are... are these just two rows of unrelated data?

Comment: Pretty much. It could be Cat and dog. Doesn't really matter.

Comment: I think I have figured it out from this [link](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-understand-the-terms-precision-and-recall).
He states: 
"So, recall is the ratio of a number of events you can correctly recall to a number of all correct events."
That would mean that recall is 420 / 620 (420 + 200)

Comment: Did you manage to get anywhere with this? I *think* my answer makes sense, but I'd rather delete it if it's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Your precision for class 1 is the number of instances correctly identified as class 1 (TP) divided by the total number of instances identified as class 1 (TP + FP). 420 were correctly identified as class 1, but 40 were incorrectly identified as class 1. So your precision for class 1 is 420/(420 + 40).

Recall for class 1 is number of instances correctly identified as class 1 (TP) divided by the total number of class 1 instances (TP + FN). 420 were correctly identified as class 1, but 60 class 1 instances were incorrectly identified as class 2. So your recall for class 1 is 420/(420 + 60).

Comment: 420 +  60 +  200 + 40 is the total amount of data.  
oneName is class 1 which has 420 correct classified instances, while 60 wrong.
twoName is class 2 which has 200 correct classified instances while 40 wrong.

Comment: So 60 of class 1 were identified as class 2?

Comment: From my understanding yes. It's from an exercise example.